# How to visualize if a button is set to trigger segue to another View Controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, segue

By holding Ctrl, clicking on a button and dragging it to another view controller, it's possible to establish the segue to move view controllers. Once this segue is created, is this connection declared somewhere in the code or in the parameters list? 
I'm opening someone else's project and I can only figure out which buttons are activating which segues by running the simulation and manually testing. When I go check the code or the segue's parameters, I can't find anything that would indicate which button is linked to which view controller transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Main.storyboard, click on the viewcontroller that you are interested in inspecting. In the top right there is a right arrow that will show you all the segue relationships and outlets

[image: I attached a picture].

Answer (score 0):

You're using Storyboards, correct?

To exemplify:

[image]

You just need to:

- **(1): click on the specific ViewController**,
- **(2): then click the Connections Inspector (2)** - it's icon that has an arrow with a circle around it -,
- **(3): and finally you'll see all the related connections (3)** to that specific ViewController. This applies to all **UIView**(s) as well.